# How to treat structures using STL iterators

Tags: c++

I am new in C++. I am using g++ compiler. I was trying to learn operations of STL library in C++. While working I found some problem in this code. Please explain the reason of the error and how to take care the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

typedef struct corrd{
int x;
int y;
}XY;

int main()
{
list<XY> values;
list<XY>::iterator current;
XY data[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    data[i].x = i+10;
    data[i].y = i+20;   
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    values.push_front(data[i]);
}
current = values.begin();
while(current!=values.end())
{
    cout<<"X coord:"<<*current->x<<endl;//error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’
    cout<<"Y coord:"<<*current->y<<endl;//error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’
    current++;
}
}
```

Comment: Don’t declare variables before use, declare them *at* first use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<*current->x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<*current->y<<endl;
```

to:

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<(*current).x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<(*current).y<<endl;
```

or

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<current->x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<current->y<<endl;
```

`current` is iterator, if you try to dereference it(*current), `*current` points to real object(x or y) is an object not pointer, so you need to call `(*current).x`.

If you don't dereference `current` iterator, you could call `operator->` to refer to the real object.

Also note that `operator->` and `operator*` have different precedence, see [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

If you store `XY` pointer in std::list, you should use iterator this way:

```
list<XY*> values;
list<XY*>::iterator current;
cout<<"X coord:"<<(*current)->x<<endl;  // parentheses is needed due to Operator Precedence
cout<<"Y coord:"<<(*current)->y<<endl;
```

Comment: In other words, it fails due to the order of operations.

Comment: No, it failed because there were TWO dereferences (both * and ->) instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You use *current to "convert" iterator to object it contains. As You have XY struct there (not as pointer but by value), you should write:

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<(*current).x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<(*current).y<<endl;
```

( "." instead of "->").

The other way to do it is to use "->" operator of iterator. It allows to use members of contained type (struct or class) directly. Then you need to write:

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<current->x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<current->y<<endl;
```

Just remove '*'

Answer (score 0):

An iterator is a bit like a generalised pointer (it has the same semantics of `*` and `->`). You're correctly using `->` to access a member of the structure the iterator points to. That member is of type `int`, so there's nothing left to dereference. So just do this:

```
cout<<"X coord:"<<current->x<<endl;
cout<<"Y coord:"<<current->y<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)" comes from the following expression: `*current->x`. What's that `int` argument of unary `*`? Well, `current->x` of course, If you look up your declaration of `x`, you'll see that it's an `int`.

So, you could write `5 * current->x`, but that's multiplication. Unary `*`, dereferencing, requires a (smart) pointer or iterator on the right.

Note that `->` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so the code is not parsed as `(*current)->x` but as `*(current->x)`